# Tensorflow to optimize a list of tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have created two lists of tensors that are multiple sizes, for example:

```
n=5
x=[placeholder(tf.float64,[i*2,None]) for i in range(n)]
y=[placeholder(tf.float64,[i*2,None]) for i in range(n)]
```

I want to use x as the input to an auto-encoder, and y as the output:
1) Is there a better way to group my tensors instead of using a list?
2) How can I ask tesnsorflow to learn simultaneously from all the tensors within x? should I use tf.group? or is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pad them into the same size with `tf.pad` and then stack them into a single tensor with `tf.stack`?

I don't think there is enough information in your question to give you a much better answer. So I would request your give more details.